# Azure datalake storage account

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

When try to create new data lake gen2 account, I am getting an error "There was an error trying to validate storage account name. Please try again"

I tried with mulitple names but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once you register "Microsoft.Storage", it should resolve the storage error.

Please go to your subscription and on the search, look for "Resource providers" => Select 'Microsoft.Storage' and on the top, click on "Register"

[image]